# JDBC: accessing remote Mysql database securely?

Tags: java, mysql, security

Is there a way to connect to a remote instance of MySQL without exposing MySQL credentials by using Java decompiler ?

If a desktop application connects to a MySQL Server, should you assign a read only access to user to access it? Is this secure enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself asking these questions then it is probably time to implement some delegated authorization. Instead of the user accessing MySQL directly from your desktop app, create a thin server layer with each user assigned a set of credentials to access. All access to the database will be mediated through this server, which will be responsible for securing the DB and ensuring only data relevant to each user is actually given to them.

Comment: thought about this too but then wouldn't it be possible to discover the intermediate server layer and simply use this server directly? anyway to restrict access to this server originating from the java desktop application?

Comment: You can never prevent the discovery of your server. This is just a reality of the internet. But, you can apply increasing levels of security in order to harden it. Keep in mind that this gets more and more expensive so you have to balance security vs usability vs frankly, importance of the data your trying to protect. To start off with I would recommend you secure your server with SSL and secure client communications using Digest Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

if your concern is to avoid password decompilation you could obfuscate your app..

you can use a read-only credential in your app, but this wouldn't prevent de compilation (however, if de compiled the user won't be able to change any data, this would be one way).

you could, use a custom class loader to load a class from the network (this class would contain the credentials)

none of the above techniques will prevent a well experienced user from de compiling and getting their hands on the credentials.